Conditional independence with a fourth random variable
Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ and three random variables $U,X,Y$.
Recall that X is conditionally independent of $Y$ given $U$ (denoted $X \perp Y | U$) if for any bounded measurable function $f$ we have $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.
$$ \mathbb{E}[ f(X) | U,Y ] = \mathbb{E}[ f(X) | U ] $$
or, equivalently, if for any two bounded measurable functions $f$ and $g$ we have $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.
$$ \mathbb{E}[ f(X) g(Y) | U ] = \mathbb{E}[ f(X) | U ] \mathbb{E}[ g(Y) | U ]. $$
Now, suppose we have a fourth random variable $V$.
It seems intuitive to me to expect $X \perp (Y,V) | (U,V)$.
How could one go about proving this?
I do not see how to reduce the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[ f(X) g(Y,V) | (U,V) ]$ to one where we condition on $U$ only to apply the hypothesis.
If it is of any help, in my context $V \perp Y | U$.
Cheers!
Edit: Here is the concise question as requested.
Premise: for any bounded measurable function $f$ it holds $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[ f(X) | U,Y ]
&= \mathbb{E}[ f(X) | U ],
\\
\mathbb{E}[ f(V) | U,Y ]
&= \mathbb{E}[ f(V) | U ].
\end{split}\end{equation}$$
Conjecture: for any bounded measurable function $f$ it holds $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.
$$
\mathbb{E}[ f(X) | U,V,Y ]
= \mathbb{E}[ f(X) | U,V ].
$$
Equivalently, for any two bounded measurable functions $f$ and $g$ it holds $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.
$$
\mathbb{E}[ f(X) g(Y,V) | U,V ]
= \mathbb{E}[ f(X) | U,V ] \cdot \mathbb{E}[ g(Y,V) | U,V ].
$$

That notation $X \perp (Y,V) | (U,V)$ looks not only awful it is also not clear. What are your premises and what the conjecture? Please write this down using conditional expectations.

@AlexRavsky I thought $U,V$ are random variables. What on earth is $(U\cap V),?$

Counterexample: The four-dimensional variable $(X,Y,U,V)$ with density function
\begin{gather*}
f(x,y,u,v)=2(1-2v)(x-2xy+y)+2v\qquad 0<x,y,u,v<1.
\end{gather*}

Could you elaborate? The way I set up the notation, the function $f$ only ever takes one argument.

It seems to me that this is not a counterexample since the density of $(U,V,Y)$ does not depend on $y$.

Indeed: $f(y,u,v)=\int_0^1(2(1-2v)(x-2xy+y)+2v)dx=1.$ And what?

That the density of $(U,V,Y)$ does not depend on $y$ implies that $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. $\mathbb{E}[g(X) | U,V,Y] = \mathbb{E}[g(X) | U,V]$ for any bounded measurable function $g$. Thus, this is not a counterexample.

That's not true. Where did you get that from?

Because the conditional density of $g(X)$ given $U,V,Y$ is given by $f_{g(X),U,V,Y} / f_{U,V,Y}$, respectively the conditional density of $g(X)$ given $U,V$ is $f_{g(X),U,V,Y} / f_{U,V}$. In this example, $f_{U,V,Y} = f_{U,V}$.

This is not true either. The conditional density of $g(X)$ given $U$ and $V$ is $f_{g(X),U,V}/f_{U,V}$. In this case: $f_{X|Y,U,V}(x|y,u,v)=2(1-2v)(x-2xy+y)+2v$ and $f_{X|U,V}(x|u,v)=1$

You are right, I see it now.
